# JAXB different datatypes parsing per namespace

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I have got the JAXB bindings config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                       parseMethod="com.utils.EmptyDateTimeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="com.utils.EmptyDateTimeAdapter.printDateTimeWithZone"/>
        <xjc:serializable uid="-1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

In xml above I declared that **every** wsdl `dateTime` element will be parsed by these methods.

My question is:
How can I change this JAXB config file to specify multiple parse methods for  element type per package name or per wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="SampleService.wsdl"          
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"          
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"          
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"          
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">  
    <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/service/SampleService/']">      
        <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">        
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date" 
                      parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>                   
    </jxb:globalBindings>  
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

references :
[JBoss Community Archive (Read Only)](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/103741)

[JAXB bindings and xs:date to java.util.Date](https://users.cxf.apache.narkive.com/rs0g14Da/jaxb-bindings-and-xs-date-to-java-util-date-conversion)

[Custom Jax-b bindings for xs:date to JAVA 8 java.time.LocalDate using Adapter](https://fusemiddleware.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/custom-jax-b-bindings-for-xsdate-to-java-8-java-time-localdate-using-adapter/)